# Kendo UI TreeListDataSource Read() only works when running locally

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo TreeList with its datasource defined as

```
    var ds = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/Home/Read/",
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }},
                     schema:...
                     }
```

My controller's read method is:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Read()
{
    log.Info("Start read()");
    var vm = vmHelper.GetClientOrgListViewModel();
    var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(vm.FacilityList);
    log.DebugFormat("json read returned: {0}", json);
    return json;
 }
```

Everything works great as long as I run locally through VS but once I deploy to our staging server, the Read() transport code never gets executed. I get a 500 error. Pressing F-12 to view the requests in IE shows a 500 error

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions on why it works locally but not on the server and how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try building your URL using `@Url.Action("Read", "Home")`

```
var ds = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: '@Url.Action("Read", "Home")',
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }},
                    schema:...
                }
```

If your javascript code is in a javascript file you won't be able to use the razor helpers. What I do in that case is add it to a list of URL's I keep in my layout file. Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Configuration;
    (function (Configuration) {
        var urls = {
            Read: '@Url.Action("Read", "Home")'
        }
        Configuration.url = urls;
    })(Configuration || (Configuration = {}));
</script>
```

Then just use it as:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: Configuration.url.Read
    }
}
```